Sitefinity share widget template
Based on the document https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/share-widget-templates
I have created a share widget template,
and in the field "This template is applied to..." I have chooses a MVC controller
( [ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "TestShare", Title = "TestShare", SectionName = "CommonWidgets")])
So, I want to know how to drag/drop that widget to multi-site/page/layout
I want to share the content of that widget between multi-site and after changing content in a site, it will change the content in all shared site.
I can't find the share widget, only see the widget I have created by code (TestShare widget).
please help me for this case.

